# Android:Crashed when run with AAR

Tags: android, aar

When I run it with module 'library', nothing happened, but when I run with AAR that is compiled by 'library', it crashed.

That's log:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/facebook/drawee/backends/pipeline/Fresco;

and that's the library's gradle:

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'   `    `
}
```

I don't want to download the source code of 'Fresco',
so how can I get 'Fresco' in some other way?

Any suggestions?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39140591/3574494

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved now.I upload library to JCenter,then inculde dependency. 
If it's helpful.